# Is it possible to somehow improve the syntax towards nested methods?

Tags: ruby

I have this method:

```rb
def prepare
  lambda do |zone, data|
    # Some code
  end
end
```

It is used like this:

```rb
prepare.call(:box, {})
```

Is there any way to get rid of `.call`? Ideally, I would like this method to be called like this:

```rb
prepare.box({})
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to use the shorter syntax to call lambdas: `prepare.(:box, {})` (without the `call` but note the `.` in front of the parentheses)? Or the method could return an object that responds to `box` and takes one argument?

Comment: `prepare` just has to return an object that responds to `box`, either as a regular method or via `method_missing`.